# Import Question

Tags: import, importexport

Newbie question.

If I want to import a new load of products and will it overwrite the existing ones or just add the new ones.

This is a real newbie question but I just want reassurance that I wont delete the 2000 products already on the site.

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SKU is used as the identifier,

- So if the SKU exists already, it will update the existing product
- If the SKU doesn't exist, it will create a new product

Comment: @Joe, if you like the answer, be sure to mark it as accepted - otherwise this site won't be around much longer :( See http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/393/cleaning-up-magento-stackexchange-com-join-magestackday